# NLTK: No value returned when searching the CMU dictionary based on syllable value

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am practicing the nltk examples from the "Natural language processing in Python" book. While trying to get the words that start with syllable "p" and of syllable length 3 from cmu dictionary (one of the examples provided in chapter 2), I am not getting any values returned. I am using Python 3. Below is the code:

> > > entries = nltk.corpus.cmudict.entries()
> > >
> > > p3 = [(pron[0] + '-' + pron[2], word)
> > >             for pron, word in entries if pron[0] == 'P' and len(pron) == 3]

But no value returned:

> > > p3 = 
> > >       []

However, I know that the value exist. See below:

> > > [(word, pron[0] + '-' + pron[2]) for word, pron in entries if word == 'perch']
> > >
> > > [('perch', 'P-CH')]

Comment: My bad, I realized the mistake. I had swapped the position of "pron" with "word" thereby causing this problem. The corrected code is "[(pron[0] + '-' + pron[2], word)
      for word, pron in entries if pron[0] == 'P' and len(pron) == 3]
"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a typo error from the OP in his code.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I realized the mistake. I had swapped the position of "pron" with "word" thereby causing this problem. The corrected code is:

> > > p3 = [(pron[0] + '-' + pron[2], word)
> > >             for word, pron in entries if pron[0] == 'P' and len(pron) == 3]
> > >       "